# SQL incremental id insert without auto key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to execute the following query as a simpler way to process several records rather than creating an insert statement for each individual one:

```
INSERT INTO wostatus (WO, STATUS, DATE, WOSTATUSID)
   SELECT  
       workorder.wonum, 'CLOSE', '02-SEP-2015', 
       (SELECT MAX(wostatusid) + 1 FROM wostatus)
   FROM  
       wostatus 
   JOIN
       workorder ON wostatus.wonum = workorder.wonum
```

However I'm getting a duplicate key error so this isn't working recursively. I thought it would keep inserting +1 and retrieving the new value for the next insert. Is there another simple way to do this that could work on both SS and Oracle?

Comment: Is it SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: This is in SQL Server 2008

Comment: your current environment is SQL Server, but you want the code to also work for Oracle - is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below query

```
INSERT INTO wostatus (WO,STATUS,DATE,WOSTATUSID)
SELECT workorder.wonum, 'CLOSE', '02-SEP-2015', ((SELECT isnull(max(wostatusid),0) from wostatus)+ row_number() over(order by wostatus.wonum))
from wostatus join workorder on wostatus.wonum = workorder.wonum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
INSERT INTO wostatus (WO,STATUS,DATE,WOSTATUSID)
SELECT 
    workorder.wonum, 
    'CLOSE', 
    '02-SEP-2015', 
    (SELECT max(wostatusid)+1 from wostatus) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
FROM wostatus 
JOIN workorder 
    ON wostatus.wonum = workorder.wonum
```

Answer (score 0):

IN TSQL you can write as:

```
DECLARE @maxwostatusid INT;
SELECT @maxwostatusid = max(wostatusid) from wostatus;

INSERT INTO wostatus (WO,STATUS,DATE,WOSTATUSID)
SELECT WO.wonum, 'CLOSE', '02-SEP-2015',
@maxwostatusid + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY WO.wonum ASC)
from wostatus WS
join workorder WO on WS.wonum = WO.wonum
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work in SQL Server 2008.

Not sure if Oracle has a similar `ROW_NUMBER()` equivalent.

```
DECLARE @MaxWoStatusId INT;

SELECT @MaxWoStatusId = MAX(wostatusid) + 1 from wostatus;

INSERT INTO wostatus (WO,STATUS,DATE,WOSTATUSID)
SELECT workorder.wonum, 'CLOSE', '02-SEP-2015', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY workorder.wonum) + @MaxWoStatusId
FROM workorder
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max);

Declare @maxv varchar(10)= (SELECT max(wostatusid)+1 from wostatus);

set @sql='INSERT INTO wostatus (WO,STATUS,DATE,WOSTATUSID)
SELECT workorder.wonum, ''CLOSE'', ''02-SEP-2015'', (SELECT '+ @maxv+'+row_number() over (order by wostatusid) from wostatus group by wostatusid)
from wostatus join workorder on wostatus.wonum = workorder.wonum '
exec (@sql);
```